# Local network speed appears to be being limited

Tags: sql-server, bandwidth, network-monitoring, network-speed

I have a dedicated server setup that has just started causing us issues.
Our immediate problem, is that last week, could log into an admin page of one of our websites just fine, now we can't.

It does do a heavy SQL procedure on the SQL database, but as its only a small usage site, im ok with that.

The problem the website is timing out, and the admin's can not log in.

It seems that when the log-in is taking place, the SQL machine and Local server are communicating ok, but the network is being severely restricted. It appears to be being capped at 1.2Mbps.

[Transfer speed graph http://driveiq.co.uk/temp/speed.png](http://driveiq.co.uk/temp/speed.png)

Its not the SQL query, this runs and completes in 5 seconds.
The script timeout on IIS is set to 120 seconds (i dont really want to extend this)
SQL machine is a physical box, the webserver is a Virtual machine
It looks like we SHOULD be getting 100 Mbps over the local network

Any ideas ?

Edit 1 : Here is a pic showing the local network between the two local machines capped at 200 bytes per second (1 meg)
If I can transfer a file at 10 Meg a second, why is SQL server only transmitting its data out at 1 Meg ? http://www.driveiq.com/temp/1meg.png

[image]

Edit 2, the INTERNET network connection is 1 MEG, is that just a coincidence that it looks like the SQL server is transmitting over the internet connection as the speed are the same?

Comment: Could you perhaps do a file transfer between the servers and see if it happens during that as well?

Comment: I did a file transfer, and that indeed went @ 10 MB

Comment: What does the SQL connection string look like? Since a file transfer between the servers is normal, is it possible that the SQL connection string is causing the SQL connection to take a different, less optimal path from the web server to the SQL server?

Comment: Hi, the SQL connection string is using the local machine name for the SQL server. "Server=SQLMachineName;Database=DatabaseName;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comparing my settings between the two SQL servers, I spotted that accounts used to operate the services where different, changing them requested a server service restart, and this fixed the issue.

oh well.